# Should I use the with statement when opening a file for a library in Python

Tags: python, json

With the `json` Python 3 library, the two most used functions are `json.load` and `json.dump` that both take a file pointer.

Since I only have one line of code using that file pointer, is it still recommended to use a `with` statement to wrap the file pointer before passing it to the function ?

For exemple should I use this :

```
def read_some_fime():
    with open(f"data/somefile.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
```

Or this :

```
def read_some_fime():
    return json.load(open(f"data/somefile.json", "r", encoding="utf-8"))
```

I'm mostly asking for the fact that the `with` statement guarantees that the file is closed, but maybe there is also a significant difference in the execution time ?

Comment: I would still use `with` here, to to be explicit but it's probably subjective

Comment: When you have a question about processing complexity or execution time, you can always test for your specific use case with the `prun` and `timeit` modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is minimal runtime overhead involved here. The `__enter__` method isn't going to do anything except return the file-like object for `json.load` to read. `__exit__` just calls its close method, and the machinery to register the `__exit__` method and ensure it is called is minimal.

I would still use the `with` statement, as it provides visual separation from the act of opening the file and the act of using it.

It's less important with `json.load`, as little or no harm can come from a read-only file not being closed. For `json.dump`, you want to ensure the file is closed in case something else causes your program to exit prematurely, possibly preventing any buffered writes from being written to disk.